# Comment Box as Facebook in flutter

Tags: flutter

**Here is my code**

```
TextField(
              controller: commentController,
              maxLines: 3,
              selectionHeightStyle: BoxHeightStyle.tight,
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Write a Comment',
                  hintStyle: new TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  prefixIcon: InkWell(
                    child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                    onTap: () {
                      chooseImage();
                    },
                  ),
                  suffixIcon: InkWell(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.send,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      if (filePickedName == 'nofile') {
                        insertMethod();
                        commentController.clear();
                        _fleshScreen();
                        getCommentData();
                      } else {
                        upload();
                        commentController.clear();
                        _fleshScreen();
                        getCommentData();
                      }
                    },
                  )),
              style: new TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              
            ),
```

**I want to create as this box with ImageView**

[facebook comment multimedia box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwLx4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me give you a widget for that

```dart
class CommentBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget image;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final BorderRadius inputRadius;
  final Function onSend,onImageRemoved;

  const CommentBox({Key key, this.image, this.controller, this.inputRadius, this.onSend , this.onImageRemoved }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CommentBoxState createState() => _CommentBoxState();
}

class _CommentBoxState extends State<CommentBox> {
  Widget image;

  @override
  void initState() {
    image = widget.image;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Divider(
          height: 1,
          color: Colors.grey[300],
          thickness: 1,
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 20),
        if (image != null)
          _removable(
            context,
            _imageView(context),
          ),
        if(widget.controller!=null) TextFormField(
          controller: widget.controller,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            suffixIcon: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.send,color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,),
              onPressed: widget.onSend,
            ),
            filled: true,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
              borderRadius: widget.inputRadius ?? BorderRadius.circular(32),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _removable(BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
      children: [
        child,
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              image = null;
              widget.onImageRemoved();
            });
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _imageView(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
        child: image,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

USE IT LIKE ANY WIDGET

```dart
MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 128,),
              Spacer(),
              CommentBox(
                image: Image.asset(
                  "assets/svg/barber.svg",
                  height: 64,
                  width: 64,
                ),
                controller: TextEditingController(),
                onImageRemoved: (){
                  //on image removed
                },
                onSend: (){
                  //on send button pressed
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```